# Rewrite a specific portion of a text file in python

Tags: python, text-files

(1) I am using Python and would like to create a function that rewrites a portion of a text file. Referencing the sample example below, I would like to be able to delete everything from [Variables] onwards and write new content from that position. I can't figure out how to achieve this using any of seek(), truncate() and/or tell().

I'm thinking I may have to read and store the file's contents up to [Variables] and write that back in before appending the new content. Is there a better way to go about this?

*(2) Bonus question: How would I do this if there was content beyond the variables section that I wanted to remain unchanged? This is currently not required, but it would be helpful to know for the future.*

**Sample Text File:**

"[Log]

This happened

That happened

etc

[Variables]

Animals: [Dog, Cat]

Number: 4"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regex:

```
import re
string = text
word = '[Variables]'
# The Regex pattern to match al characters on and after '[Variables]'
pattern  = word + ".*"
# Remove all characters after '[Variables]' from string
string = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
print(string)
```

Here if the text is the text that you show on your question, the output of the code will be:

```
"[Log]

This happened

That happened

etc"
```

In order to add new text at the end you just need to concatenate a new string to the existing one like:

```
string += "Some Text"
```

Comment: @CarlosHorn you changed variable `str` into `string` because ther is built-in `str` - but there is also standard module `string` and using this name as variable can be also wrong idea ;)

Comment: @furas, good point, but the problem weights differently, you can always import as to manage your local namespace, but you cannot get your `str` back (easily) because it is by default in your local namespace.

Comment: This worked differently depending on the string (I named it as "script") I defined. I can get it to work where the first portion before the marker/word is printed out as in your example result. But if I do: "with open("seek.txt", 'r+') as data:
    script = data.read()" it returns the entire script excluding the line with the marker/word which is a step towards what I wanted in the (2) part of my question.